# Customizing Pyramid error messages

Tags: python, error-handling, pyramid

I'm trying to find a way to customize error messages (404, 403) in my Pyramid application. I've found [this doc](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/dev/narr/hooks.html#changing-the-notfound-view), but it's still not clear how to do it.

What I need to do it to render one of the templates (say, templates/404.pt) instead of standard 404 message. I've added following to my `__init__.py`:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPNotFound

import myapp.views.errors as error_views

<...>

def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.add_static_view('static', 'myapp:static')
    config.add_route(...)
    <...>
    config.add_view(error_views.notfound, context=HTTPNotFound)
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Where error_views.notfound looks like

```
def notfound(request):
    macros = get_template('../templates/macros.pt')
    return {
            'macros': macros,
            'title': "HTTP error 404"
            }
```

Sure it does not works (how do I specify template name in this case?), and even more: it seems view is not called at all and it's code ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass to add_view as context a `pyramid.exceptions` exception, not a `pyramid.httpexceptions`one.

This works for me:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """
    This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    ...
    config.add_view('my_app.error_views.not_found_view',
        renderer='myapp:templates/not_found.pt',
        context='pyramid.exceptions.NotFound')
```

Comment: In Pyramid 1.1 (available on PyPI) this is resolved... NotFound and Forbidden have been merged into their respective HTTPException objects.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your myapp.views.errors file:

```
from pyramid.renderers import render_to_response

def notfound(request):
    context['title'] = "HTTP error 404"
    return render_to_response('../templates/macros.pt', context)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's how my view should probably look like, but... it does not works. I can even write there things like `a = b / 0` and no exception logged anywhere. So, it seems I'm doing something wrong when adding a view.

Answer (score 2):

From Pyramid 1.3 it's enough to use `@notfound_view_config` decorator. There is no need to set anything in `__init__.py` now. There is example code for views.py:

```
from pyramid.view import notfound_view_config
@notfound_view_config(renderer='error-page.mako')
def notfound(request):
    request.response.status = 404
    return {}
```